# Show existing git repository in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git-slave server and on this server has some git project (git repository), now I installed Gitlab-CE on that server and want to show old git repo in Gitlab for code review, and the problem is when I try to clone repo by URL Gitlab return this error:

```
Every import attempt has failed: Error importing repository http://*****@127.0.0.1/srv/git/repo2/.git into root/repo24 - 13:CreateRepositoryFromURL: clone cmd wait: exit status 128. Please try again.
```

and when I want to change Gitlab repository location, Gitlab change permission the old directory (existing git slave repositories) and that's the solution also not helpful.

What should I do? any solution?